# Как скопировать файл в Python, если он не имеет расширения?

Tags: python, copy, shutil

Возникла проблема, из-за которой я должным образом не могу скопировать нужный мне файл, а точнее его содержимое в другой файл. Проблема в том, что первый файл, из которого копируется содержимое, просто не имеет расширения. Его можно открыть, но только с помощью текстовых редакторов или программы SQL Cipher (сам файл, это база данных SQLite).

Пробовал только модуль "shutil' (других не знаю).

Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: Непонятно, вам нужно просто скопировать файл или что нужно?

Comment: Да, мне нужно скопировать файл из одной директории в другую. Но проблема в том, что файл не имеет конкретного расширения (у файла просто название и белая иконка)

Comment: Здесь 2 варианта, либо у вас скрыты(не отображаются) расширения файлов в (windows), либо просто его случайно удалили. Если нет расширения переименовать файл и добавить  к нему .sqlite3 Должно работать

Comment: Все расширения файлов отображаются, кроме этого. Этот файл принадлежит браузеру Google, и хранит мои Cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Предположительно файл является бинарным, следовательно его нужно открывать в бинарном формате для чтения и записи. Если требуется только скопировать, можно вызвать функцию операционной системы.

```
bin_file=open('path','rb').read()
with open('new','wb') as f:
   f.write(bin_file)
   f.flush()
```

но данный метод не подходит для больших файлов, нужно будет ставить ограничение на запись-чтение

```
os.system('cp "file" "to_file"')
```

данный метод будет платформозависимым то есть нужно вызывать системную функцию

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле сделать это очень просто с помощью модуля shutil.
Покажу как!

```
import shutil
shutil.copyfile('C:\Project\tvoyfile', 'C:\Project5\hell.txt').format
```

На деле здесь можно много что поменять, например вместо пути подставить переменную с путем работы программа, или производить копирование содержимого файла так же в файл без формата, в общем, играйтесь!